# Groovy .each only iterates one time

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

The script is not iterating through all the values of the 'modules' array.

```html
class Module {
    public String name = '';
    public Boolean isCustom = false;
    public Module(String name, Boolean custom){
        this.name = name;
        this.isCustom = custom;
    }
}

//creates array from the ext_module env var
modules = [];
EXT_MODULE.split(',').each { 
    modules.add(new Module(it, false));
}


println modules;
modules.each {  
    println "MODULE NAME ::::: ${it.name}"
    if(it.isCustom)
    {
        println "install custom";
    } else {
        println "install non custom";
    }
};
```

This is the result of the run. The array shows 4 elements, but the code inside the .each black only executes once.

> Running: Print Message
>   [Module@71f09325, Module@e1ddb41, Module@7069a674, Module@1f68f952]
>   Running: Print Message
>   MODULE NAME ::::: puppetlabs-ntp
>   Running: Print Message
>   install non custom
>   Running: End of Workflow
>   Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: This seems to be a Jenkins DSL specific problem.  For whatever reason it works if you change the modules.each => for(module in modules), can anyone tell me why?

Comment: just so: `def modules = EXT_MODULE.split(',').collect{ new Module(it, false) }`.  everytime you use `each` to build collections, a kitty dies.  the fact, that there is no `def` is ok with jenkins(-scriptler); you are not messing with some global state here?

Comment: My guess is there is some kind of global closure that is affected by the .each and is messing up the Jenkins build process

Comment: I tried to run your script whilst setting EXT_MODULE to "a,b,c". Managed to get it to execute three times.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The messages "Running: Print Message" and "Running: End of Workflow" indicate that you are using the new workflow plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin. This plugin currently has a bug causing at least some Groovy iterations involving a closure to be aborted after one iteration: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481

Answer (score 4):

The workaround is to simply use an old school for loop `(code below)`.
Also, NonCPS is another workaround.
There is an open issue for this matter. See here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481

**Update, Oct 24th, 2016**

/**
     * Dumps environment varibles to the log, using **an old school for loop.**
     */

```
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS

def version = '1.0'

@NonCPS
def dumpEnvVars() {
  def str = "Dumping build environment variables...\n"
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : currentBuild.build().environment) {
    str += "    ${entry.key} = ${entry.value}\n"
  }
  echo str
}

return this;
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing an example of "old school for loop".

Answer (score 0):

As of yesterday, the new Pipeline plugin was delivered in version 2.0 and correct this problem.

`.each` closures now work, but `.collect` still only iterate once.

Comment: I am using Jenkins 2.x, and all my pipeline plugins are 2.x, except for the milestone plugin.  Still, each() iterates just once.

Comment: They went back and forward with this implementation. But I think it isn't working at the moment, and I've given up on it in the end.

Comment: Likewise I have everything at 2.0 or better and .each iterates only once (as well as everything else I tried)