# Currying groovy CPS closure for parallel execution

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, closures, jenkins-pipeline, currying

We do some dynamic creation of parallel steps in some of our jobs. Thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631959/jenkins-workflow-parallelize-step-based-on-tool-output) I found how to dynamically create the map with parameters for use in the parallel step.

However now I wanted to reuse parts of the code which is used to create those parallel steps. For this I feel that I would need to curry the closures.

However currying seems not to work correctly. Referencing the loop variable (valueCopy) inside the closure does the right thing ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631959/jenkins-workflow-parallelize-step-based-on-tool-output)) but currying does not do what I would expect.

Am I doing something wrong, is this just not (yet) supported, are there any workarounds? Is this probably a bug in Jenkins pipeline?

Hope anybody has a clue why this doesn't work and/or how to get it working.

Jenkins: LTS (2.32.1) & latest plugin updates as of 2017/01/19.

### Solution:

**After upgrading to Pipeline: Groovy plugin version 2.40 eveything is working as expected now.**

Pipeline script executed:

```java
def echoSome(val) {
    echo val
}

def buildClosures() {
    def someList = ["1", "2", "3"]
    def closures = [:]
    for (value in someList) {
        final valueCopy = value

        closures[value] = {val ->
                echo valueCopy.toString()
                echo val.toString()
            }.curry(value)
    }
    closures
}

parallel buildClosures()
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [1] { (Branch: 1)
[Pipeline] [2] { (Branch: 2)
[Pipeline] [3] { (Branch: 3)
[Pipeline] [1] echo
[1] 1
[Pipeline] [1] echo
[1] 3
[Pipeline] [1] }
[Pipeline] [2] echo
[2] 2
[Pipeline] [2] echo
[2] 3
[Pipeline] [2] }
[Pipeline] [3] echo
[3] 3
[Pipeline] [3] echo
[3] 3
[Pipeline] [3] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Expected Output:

```
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [1] { (Branch: 1)
[Pipeline] [2] { (Branch: 2)
[Pipeline] [3] { (Branch: 3)
[Pipeline] [1] echo
[1] 1
[Pipeline] [1] echo
[1] 1
[Pipeline] [1] }
[Pipeline] [2] echo
[2] 2
[Pipeline] [2] echo
[2] 2
[Pipeline] [2] }
[Pipeline] [3] echo
[3] 3
[Pipeline] [3] echo
[3] 3
[Pipeline] [3] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that with the latest [Pipeline: Groovy](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-cps) plugin (2.40) combined with at least Jenkins Version 2.60.3 (works although the plug-ins homepage states that you need at least Jenkins 2.73.3) everything works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it's the currying, or the for loop, but this function needs to be marked as NonCPS as described here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md#groovy-gotchas

Essentially, do this:

```
@NonCPS
def buildClosures() {
    def someList = ["1", "2", "3"]
    def closures = [:]
    for (value in someList) {
        final valueCopy = value

        closures[value] = {val ->
                echo valueCopy.toString()
                echo val.toString()
            }.curry(value)
    }
    closures
}
```

I think it's your for loop, but regardless, anytime you don't use classic "C Style" loops, you'll need to mark your function as NonCPS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason I was not notified :(. I'll give it a try as soon as possible.

Comment: Marked as solved as this really solves my question. Unfortunately I missed to  mention that of course I'd like to use CPS code inside the parallel closures :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a limitation of either the Groovy language or the Jenkins groovy runtime, I'm not sure which, but it's worth noting their examples do exactly as you have done, declaring a new variable for each iteration of the loop.

They have commented their example

> // fresh variable per iteration; i will be mutated

I don't think that using C-style loops will remove this limitation and currying (which would be required for this use case) does not resolve the issue either. Clumsy, but easy enough to work around.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#creating-multiple-threads