# Why does this String→List→Map conversion doesn't work in Groovy

Tags: groovy, data-conversion

I have input data of type

```
abc    12d
uy     76d
ce     12a
```

with the lines being separated by `\n` and the values by `\t`.

The data comes from a shell command:

```
brlist = 'mycommand'.execute().text
```

Then I want to get this into a map:

```
brmap = brlist.split("\n").collectEntries {
          tkns = it.tokenize("\t")
          [ (tkns[0]): tkns[1] ]
        }
```

I also tried

```
brmap = brlist.split("\n").collectEntries {
          it.tokenize("\t").with { [ (it[0]): it[1] ] }
        }
```

Both ways gave the same result, which is a map with a single entry:

```
brmap.toString()
# prints "[abc:12d]"
```

Why does only the first line of the input data end up being in the map?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, which means the input String `brlist` isn't what you say it is...

Are you sure that's what you have?  Try printing `brlist`, and then `it` inside `collectEntries`

As an aside, this does the same thing as your code:

```
brlist.split('\n')*.split('\t')*.toList().collectEntries()
```

Or you could try (incase it's spaces not tabs, this will expect both)

```
brlist.split('\n')*.split(/\s+/)*.toList().collectEntries()
```

Comment: That code doesn't run. I'm using the Jenkins Groovy Pipeline script. `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.split() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ ]
Possible solutions: split(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), init(), sort(), tail(), toList()`

Answer (score 1):

This code works

```
// I use 4 spaces as tab.
def text = 'sh abc.sh'.execute().text.replaceAll(" " * 4, "\t")
brmap = text.split("\n").collectEntries {
    tkns = it.tokenize("\t")
    [(tkns[0]) : tkns[1]]
}
assert[abc:"12d", uy:"76d", ce:"12a"] == brmap
```

abc.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "abc    12d"
echo "uy    76d"
echo "ce    12a
```

Also, I think your groovy code is correct. maybe your `mycommand` has some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the hints, it is a bug in Jenkins: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481.

And it has been mentioned here before: [Groovy .each only iterates one time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509344/groovy-each-only-iterates-one-time)